# How to create a polling mechanism with kotlin coroutines?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-sharedflow

I am trying to create a polling mechanism with kotlin coroutines using `sharedFlow` and want to stop when there are no subscribers and active when there is at least one subscriber. My question is, is `sharedFlow` the right choice in this scenario or should I use `channel`. I tried using `channelFlow` but I am unaware how to close the channel (not `cancel` the job) outside the block body. Can someone help? Here's the snippet.

```
 fun poll(id: String) = channelFlow {
            while (!isClosedForSend) {
                try {
                    send(repository.getDetails(id))
                    delay(MIN_REFRESH_TIME_MS)
                } catch (throwable: Throwable) {
                    Timber.e("error -> ${throwable.message}")
                }
                invokeOnClose { Timber.e("channel flow closed.") }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just use a rendezvous (unbuffered) channel.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Can you post a small snippet of what you mean?

Answer (score 2):

You can use SharedFlow which emits values in a broadcast fashion (won't emit new value until the previous one is consumed by all the collectors).

```
val sharedFlow = MutableSharedFlow<String>()
val scope = CoroutineScope(Job() + Dispatchers.IO)
var producer: Job()

scope.launch {
    val producer = launch() {
            sharedFlow.emit(...)
    }

    sharedFlow.subscriptionCount
              .map {count -> count > 0}
              .distinctUntilChanged()
              .collect { isActive -> if (isActive) stopProducing() else startProducing()
}

fun CoroutineScope.startProducing() {
    producer = launch() {
        sharedFlow.emit(...)
    }
        
}

fun stopProducing() {
    producer.cancel()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, when you call channelFlow(block), there is no need to close the channel manually. The channel will be closed automatically after the execution of block is done.

I think the "produce" coroutine builder function may be what you need. But unfortunately, it's still an experimental api.

```
fun poll(id: String) = someScope.produce {
    invokeOnClose { Timber.e("channel flow closed.") }

    while (true) {
        try {
            send(repository.getDetails(id))
//          delay(MIN_REFRESH_TIME_MS)   //no need
        } catch (throwable: Throwable) {
            Timber.e("error -> ${throwable.message}")
        }
    }
}

fun main() = runBlocking {
    val channel = poll("hello")

    channel.receive()

    channel.cancel()
}
```

The produce function will suspended when you don't call the returned channel's receive() method, so there is no need to delay.

***UPDATE:*** Use `broadcast` for sharing values across multiple ReceiveChannel.

```
fun poll(id: String) = someScope.broadcast {
    invokeOnClose { Timber.e("channel flow closed.") }

    while (true) {
        try {
            send(repository.getDetails(id))
//          delay(MIN_REFRESH_TIME_MS)   //no need
        } catch (throwable: Throwable) {
            Timber.e("error -> ${throwable.message}")
        }
    }
}

fun main() = runBlocking {
    val broadcast = poll("hello")

    val channel1 = broadcast.openSubscription()
    val channel2 = broadcast.openSubscription()
    
    channel1.receive()
    channel2.receive()

    broadcast.cancel()
}
```

Comment: does `produce` allow you to share the same values across multiple terminal operators `collect`? not sure if it can do that

Comment: Then try `broadcast` function. I will update my answer.

Comment: Why is there no need for the delay?